# Are DLLs in IIS loaded under the .NET framework specified in the web.config or what they are built against?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, dotnetnuke

I hope someone can clarify this for me.

I'm running an ASP.NET website in IIS (DotNetNuke to be exact).  I also have a module that is installed on the site that was custom built.

My IIS web.config specifies a "targetFramework" of "4.5" (under the system.web/httpRuntime element).
My custom module was built with a target framework of "4.7.2".

When the custom module is loaded by the website, is it now running under the .NET 4.5 framework because that's what the website's web.config was targetting?

Answer (score 0):

The targetFramework in httpRuntime indicates that the application uses Framework4.5 assembly when running in IIS.

Even if the application selects .NET 4.7 when it is created, it can still run under the environment of .NET 4.5. Compatibility will be ensured when .NET is upgraded. Only when major versions are upgraded, there may be incompatibility issues, such as .NET 3 to .NET 4.

For a detailed explanation of httpRuntime, you can refer to this [Microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/).